# Autoresizing form in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a [script](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) for autosizing forms. The problem is that it stops working the second time around in a loop. I'm guessing this is because I need to give it a unique id but I'm not sure how to do that since the jquery is not in the loop. The html looks like this:

```
<textarea class="text required comment" id="283" name="comment" placeholder="Add a comment..."></textarea>
```

and the form code looks like this:

```
<% post.each do |post| %>
 <%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment, as: :text, input_html: { :class => "comment", :id => "#{post.id}" }, placeholder: "Add a comment..." %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my posts.js.coffee file I have this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("textarea").autosize()
```

Comment: Can you plz show js code. How you bind autosize to your input?

Comment: Any errors in the console?